# ng-change not working even sometimes with Select tag?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-select2

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-change="retrieveSelectedClass()" ng-options="(item.name||item) group by item.groupName for item in names"
            class="code-helper" id="code-helperId">
        <option value="">Select Option</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var globalEditor1 = null;
var globalMergeEditor = null;
var widgets = [];
var timeout;
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
var previousValue;

app.controller('OrderFormController', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.retrieveSelectedClass = function() {
        $scope.isPaneShown = true;
        if ($scope.selectedName === undefined) {
            $scope.isPaneShown = false;
            return;
        }
        if ($scope.selectedName.groupName === 'Create New') {
            if (globalEditor1) {
                if (!globalEditor1.isClean()) {
                    var r = confirm("You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to proceed ?");
                    if (r != true) {
                        $('.code-helper').val(previousValue);
                        $scope.isPaneShown = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            $scope.isPaneShown = false;

        } else {
            if (globalEditor1) {
                if (!globalEditor1.isClean()) {
                    var r = confirm("You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to proceed ?");
                    if (r != true) {
                        $('.code-helper').val(previousValue);
                        $scope.isPaneShown = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.code-helper').select2({
        placeholder: 'Select a command to begin'
    });
    $('.code-helper').on('select2:selecting', function(evt) {
        console.log($('.code-helper').val());
        previousValue = $('.code-helper').val();

    });
});
```

I have ng-model, attached, but still sometimes the ng-change function is not getting called, this happens only in this scenario.

When a change is detected: `!globalEditor1.isClean() = true` then I am trying to replace the `selected value` with the previous value.
This happens fine. But now when I try to change the value from `select` tag, it does not fire the `ng-change` event.

**jsfiddle**

[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/2m6cbrtu/)

Steps to reproduce:

Try the following: run the link again.
then step

1) From the drop down select "AccountProcessorTest"
2) select ok from alert
3) Select "AddPrimaryContact" and from alert select cancel
4) now the previous value is retained.
5) now select "AddPrimaryContact" again.

The event wont fire.

Comment: `ng-change` will surely trigger, what might not triggering is the `condition` that you have applied in `if` block. Can you create a plunkr to show an example

Comment: I will create a plunkr, but I have also kept a debugger point right on ` $scope.isPaneShown = true;` this line, but it never hits that, also a console.log..

Comment: @ShashankVivek I have created a jsfiddle link.

Try the following: run the link again.
then step 1) From the drop down select "AccountProcessorTest"
2) select ok from alert
3) Select "AddPrimaryContact" and from alert select cancel
4) now the previous value is retained.
5) now select "AddPrimaryContact" again.

The event wont fire.

Comment: It seems like a bug, its not a good practice to mix `jquery` and `angularJS`. On the top of that, its a jquery plugin. So better to for angularJS plugin

Comment: don't mix angular and jquery like this.  your angular function triggers, then if the condition is true, you use jquery to make a change that angular doesn't know about.  as far as angular is concerned, the value is still the new one, even though you used jquery to set the value to a previous value.  `ng-change` therefore never triggers when you pick that option a second time, because as far as angular is concerned, the value didn't change.  Bottom line, don't use jquery to change angular variables, **EVER.**

Comment: @Claies Going with your suggestion, I have created ui-select tags. But it does not do a proper search and the scroll bar gets stuck at "loading..." when it reaches at last. https://jsfiddle.net/2m6cbrtu/3/

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
ng-change="retrieveSelectedClass(selectedName, '{{selectedName}}')"
```

**JS**

```
$scope.retrieveSelectedClass = function(newValue, oldValue) {
    var oldValueSelected = {};
if (angular.isUndefined(oldValueSelected.id) && oldValue.indexOf('"id"') !== -1) {
    oldValueSelected = JSON.parse(oldValue);
}
var possibleOldValues = $filter('filter')($scope.names, {
    id: oldValueSelected.id
}, true);
oldValue = possibleOldValues[0];

}
```